# How to set expectation on a mocked method which is called inside another mocked method Rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust, actix-web, mockall

I am attempting to mock a method from a trait that returns another mock. I've tried creating two separate mock instances and having them return sequentially, but I've been unsuccessful. How can I solve this situation?

I am getting an error

no method named `returning` found for mutable reference `&mut __get_account_query::Expectation` in the current scope
method not found in `&mut Expectation`

**My handler**

```
pub struct AppState {
    db: Box<dyn QueryDependency>,
}

#[post("/create")]
pub async fn create_account(
    data: web::Data<AppState>
) -> impl Responder {
     ..... 
     .....
    let result = data.db.get_account_query().create_account(&new_account).await;
                           ^^ the function I am trying to mock here
}  


#[actix_web::test]
async fn create_account_test() {
        let mock_db = MockQueryDependency::new();
        let mut mock_account_query = MockAccountQuery::new();

        mock_account_query
            .expect_create_account()
            .times(1)
            .returning(|_| Ok(Account {
                id: 1,
                name = "test".to_string(),
            }));
        
        mock_db.expect_get_account_query().times(1).returning(|| &mock_account_query);

        let mock_state = AppState {
            db: Box::new(mock_db),
        };
}
```

**My traits**

```
#[cfg(test)]
use mockall::automock;

#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
pub trait QueryDependency: Send + Sync {
    fn get_account_query(&self) -> &dyn AccountQuery;
}

#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
#[async_trait]
pub trait AccountQuery: Send + Sync {
    async fn create_account(&self, new_account: &NewAccount) -> Result<Account, sqlx::Error>;
}
```

Comment: Nested mocks is the design equivalent of a code smell. Think carefully before proceeding. Generally functions that do I/O should insofar as is possible just delegate to pure functions. The pure function is easy to unit test, and the I/O function doesn't need unit tests. The structure of your code might be problematic, and your testing woes might be trying to tell you something...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, say if i have a pure function that takes in a connection for sqlx queries. Then this sqlx functions is being used somewhere inside a function. Will i always have to mock this and inject into the function for test cases usage?

Comment: I'm going to stray from the fairly uncontroversial advice I gave before into more contested territory: create_account doesn't need a unit test. All you are doing is calling a db function and piping the result back to the client. That needs an *integration* test to make sure e.g. the error handling works if it fails, but I seriously doubt you're accomplishing anything useful by these mock heavy unit tests. "i have a pure function that takes in a connection for sqlx queries" then it's not a pure function. Doing something with a db connection is *I/O*, and it doesn't need a unit test.

Comment: ...[cont] whereas processing the data is business logic and *does* need unit tests, and such operations can (and should) be made pure. Business logic is what needs unit tests, not the plumbing. Plumbing is for *integration or e2e tests*. Route handlers in a backend web framework should not need unit tests.